# Reduce OCR android app's size

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I made an OCR app using tesseract OCR engine and android studio using this tutorial
http://androidadvance.com/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-tessaract-ocr-in-android-android-studio/
The size of the app is 1.5GB, how can i reduce the size?

Thanks.

Comment: What you want to reduce apk size or project size??

Comment: Project size, the size of the Tesseract library is 1.4GB, so if there is anyway to reduce it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reduce the size :

When you compile test-two project with ndk two folders  created.

1. libs
2. obj

In *libs* folder *.so* file generated and also other folder name *obj* generated. The *obj* folder size is very big so you need to delete this folder and check your project size. Do not delete *libs* folder.